# android: get a LinearLayout over an ImageView

Tags: android, layout

I want an ImageView to cover the left half of the screen while keeping aspect ratio and a LinearLayout at the same position with the same width and height. Can anyone tell me how to achieve that?

Comment: use FrameLayout as a parent layout.

Comment: can u plz elaborate?

Comment: Can you Share Screen Design

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like this as your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_linear_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/your_image_view"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="image"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your activity or fragment you will have to programmatically set the LinearLayout's height and width to match the ImageView.

```
ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
int ivHeight = iv.getHeight();
int ivWidth = iv.getWidth(); 

LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout);
LayoutParams llParams = ll.getLayoutParams();

llParams.height = ivHeight;
llParams.width = ivWidth

ll.setLayoutParams(llParams);
```

The "src" tag will ensure that the image's aspect ratio is preserved. Keep in mind that you will have to handle resize after rotation this way as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
      </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why you take extra Relative Layout in LinearLayout

Comment: I used weight 1, so need 2 layouts